# Join on most recent date and by partition

Tags: sql, join, partition, row-number

I have two tables,
clicks:

```
user    date
a   01/10/2021
a   02/10/2021
a   03/10/2021
b   27/09/2021
c   08/10/2021
c   13/10/2021
```

and segment:

```
user    date    segment
a   26/09/2021  1
a   27/09/2021  1
a   03/10/2021  2
c   01/10/2021  5
c   10/10/2021  6
```

I want to join segment to clicks to identify the latest segment per user on that given click date. So the correct output will look like this:

```
user    date    segment
a   01/10/2021  1
a   02/10/2021  1
a   03/10/2021  2
b   27/09/2021  
c   08/10/2021  5
c   13/10/2021  6
```

I have tried the following but get the error *'this type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error'*

```
    select *,
   (select top 1 segment
    from b
    where
          b.date <= a.date
    ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY b.id ORDER BY b.date DESC)) as segment_lookup
from a;
```

Any help greatly appreciated to find the best method. Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the database? Looks like Sybase or SQL Server by the use of `TOP`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention the database so I'll assume it's SQL Server.

Also, the first table doesn't seem to have a key so the query below uses (`user`, `date`) as a key.

You can do:

```
select *
from (
  select
    c.*, s.segment,
    row_number() over(partition by c.u, c.d order by s.d desc) as rn
  from clicks c
  left join segment s on s.u = c.u and c.d >= s.d
) x
where rn = 1
```

Result:

```
 u  d           segment  rn 
 -- ----------- -------- -- 
 a  2021-10-01  1        1  
 a  2021-10-02  1        1  
 a  2021-10-03  2        1  
 b  2021-09-27           1  
 c  2021-10-08  5        1  
 c  2021-10-13  6        1
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle 1](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bd887fe51b031b8b81f558c90a53d91a).

Alternatively, you can use a lateral join that could theoretically have better performance.

**EDIT: Adding lateral join as requested**

The query with a lateral join can take the form:

```
select
  c.*, s.segment
from clicks c
outer apply (
  select top 1 * from segment s where s.u = c.u and c.d >= s.d
  order by s.d desc
) s
```

Result:

```
 u  d           segment 
 -- ----------- ------- 
 a  2021-10-01  1       
 a  2021-10-02  1       
 a  2021-10-03  2       
 b  2021-09-27          
 c  2021-10-08  5       
 c  2021-10-13  6
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f49b0f124b5dc7d3b706a26fd1e63618).

The lateral join could be quite performant if the index `segment (u, d)` is created.

Comment: Thank you - this worked perfectly. I'd be really interested to see an example of a lateral join as well to improve performance. Can you please share?

Comment: @Blake Example added.